# Getting four smaller sub date ranges from a larger one

Tags: powershell

**Question (short version):**

Is the following a sufficient way to break up a date range into 4 even ones ?

**Longer Reasoning (skip if you want):**

I have been trying to think of ways of speeding up getting the Windows Application logs via powershell script and my latest thought is to divide the date ranges into four requests which can run at the same time.

**Code:**

Seems to work, any other ideas or opinions?

```
# Example range
$StartDate = (get-date).Addminutes(-10000)
$EndDate = (get-date) 

# get 1/4 mins 
$Mins = (($EndDate - $StartDate).TotalMinutes /4)

$Start = $null
$End = $null 

for ($i = 1; $i -le 4; $i++) {

    if (!$Start) {
        $Start = $startDate
        $End = $StartDate.AddMinutes($Mins)
    } Else {
        $Start = $End.AddSeconds(1)
        $End = $End.AddMinutes($Mins)
    }

    Write-Host($Start)
    Write-Host($End)
    ' '
}
```

Output:

```
3/2/2023 8:29:53 PM
3/4/2023 2:09:53 PM
 
3/4/2023 2:09:54 PM
3/6/2023 7:49:53 AM
 
3/6/2023 7:49:54 AM
3/8/2023 1:29:53 AM
 
3/8/2023 1:29:54 AM
3/9/2023 7:09:53 PM
```

**UPDATE:**

Per discussions in this group I have attempted to create means to read logs using eventlogreader in powershell. It's currently working but the results need to be figured out.

```
using namespace System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader
$Log = $null 
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

try {

    # Filters
    $start = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddHours(-1).ToString('o')
    $end = [datetime]::UtcNow.ToString('o')

    $filter = "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']]] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{1}']]]" -f $start, $end

    # Query
    $query = [EventLogQuery]::new('Application', [PathType]::LogName, $filter)
    $query.Session = [EventLogSession]::new($Computer)

    # Read
    $reader = [EventLogReader]::new($query)
    while($log = $reader.ReadEvent()) {
        $log
    }

}
finally {
    if ($reader) {
        $reader.Dispose()
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

*What is Fastest?*

Thanks to everyone's suggestions, the method above is the fastest way of getting large amounts of data. Using get-winevent with filters is fast for getting very specific things which may not return a lot of logs. Lastly I would stay away grom Get-EventLog.

*Tweaks Made for Speed?*

In addition to the code above using start-job can make things faster. Code takes every function that is to be run on every server and puts it into a single queue. Then using start-job calls them concurrently. The # of jobs are not to exceed the number of cores at any given time and it keeps as many as possible going at once.

Comment: Are you using `get-winevent -filterhashtable`?

Comment: you're querying the same source, I doubt doing this in parallel will improve your runtime and might even worsen it

Comment: Doing tasks in parallel does not necessarily speed up performance.  Windows is a multi-task operating system that is swapping system tasks at higher priority than normal operating tasks.  There is also an overhead associated with the swapping.  And when memory reaches 100% disk space is used for swapping which is slower than normal memory.  So you only get speed improvement when you do not reach 100% memory usage.  When you processor has mult-cores swapping parallel task will give better performance than single core.

Comment: @js2010 yes. I have pushed get-winevent to it's limit of capabilities I believe. Use get-winevent, use filterhashtable, be specific about what you want if you can, etc.. The issue is that I am grabbing 100 hours of history. I'm currently using threadjob to do some of this already.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon From my testing it could help, it's actually much more effienct to ask get-winevent a bunch of specific things at once then for an entire log for example for a date range. I am using 'threadjob' to do much of this already.

Comment: @jdweng all of what you said may be true but honestly I have been splitting up the get-winevent tasks and running them through threadjob and it is much quicker

Comment: You are using more of the cores, but eventually you will run out of cores.  The other answers are same the same as me.  That as you add more tasks the amount of gain gets smaller and smaller until you get no more gain and even will start to perform worse.

Comment: Does your application log get bigger than 20 megs (the default)?  Also filtering other things will make it faster, like id, level, userid, data, etc.

Comment: @jdweng to your point, I found that 'threading' helps as long as you limit the number of jobs running at one time.  I basically call on my system up to 20 at any given time and feed in more as others finish. This seems to be the fastest because it speeds up the slow running jobs. So to that point I front load my queue with those since I know what they are. Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: @js2010 Thanks for your feedback. Get-WinEvent is good as long as you are not trying to read a LOT of data. In my case I upgraded to the above method (.net) and use 'threading', it was a bit faster but probably not worth it for most people. I got multiple servers to read and inspect the application log along with a bunch of other tasks which include using get-winevent down to about 1 minute for several hours of history. I am writing a tool that IT support use so they need to have it work quickly. I have added comments to my post along with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise would be, don't use `Get-WinEvent` which is what you're probably using now and is slowing you down. There is no need to query the events in parallel, since the source is the same I believe this will not give you an edge and might even worsen performance. Rely on .NET and it should be good.

For simple comparison querying all Application logs:

```bash
using namespace System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader

$test = @{
    'EventLogReader' = {
        try {
            $query  = [EventLogQuery]::new('Application', [PathType]::LogName)
            $reader = [EventLogReader]::new($query)

            while($log = $reader.ReadEvent()) {
                $log
            }
        }
        finally {
            if($reader) {
                $reader.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    'Get-WinEvent' = {
        Get-WinEvent -LogName Application
    }
}

$test.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Test              = $_.Key
        TotalMilliseconds = (Measure-Command { & $_.Value }).TotalMilliseconds
    }
}
```

Gives me these results:

```bash
Test           TotalMilliseconds
----           -----------------
EventLogReader          536.0044
Get-WinEvent          11754.7131
```

If you need to filter by a time range you can use something like this:

```bash
$start = [datetime]::UtcNow.Addminutes(-10000).ToString('o')
$end   = [datetime]::UtcNow.ToString('o')

$filter = "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']]] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{1}']]]" -f $start, $end
$query  = [EventLogQuery]::new('Application', [PathType]::LogName, $filter)
$reader = [EventLogReader]::new($query)
```

Then do the same logic with the `while` loop and dispose the reader when done.

Comment: Thanks, I can't figure out how to call against a remote host. I searched the web and found this: $eventLogReader = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader("\\$remoteComputerName\$logName") but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeQ use `Invoke-Command` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. I have attempted to create a session and read the data from a remote host using EventLogQuery and it works but the output is a little wonky. I posted my code in the original post. Do you have any opinions etc. ?  I figured out the session thing from looking at some C# code today.

Comment: @MikeQ nicely done, code looks good to me. Im not sure what you mean by wonky. The output should be very similar to `Get-WinEvent`, the difference is that `Get-WinEvent` calls `.FormatDescription()` on each log and then attaches the `.Message` property to the event (this is mainly what makes `Get-WinEvent` so slow). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord.formatdescription?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-diagnostics-eventing-reader-eventrecord-formatdescription

Comment: This is the fastest way and I find it interesting that with this method I don't have to pair down the data pull to specific items because it's about the same speed no matter what. What I did in addition is to run it through a queue of 'thread jobs' and importantly limit the number of jobs that can run at one time (in my case 20). It has saved minutes from my tool. thanks again. I have final comments above in my original post.

Comment: @MikeQ I'm glad the answer was helpful. I have ran some tests from my side and I got to say that the only reason why `Get-WinEvent` is slow compared to calling the API as shown in this answer is mainly for 2 reasons: 1. the cmdlet calls `.FormatDescription()` on each event it pulls, which by itself is very expensive and 2. the cmdlet attaches the result string from that method to the `.Message` property to every log which is also quite expensive

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Updated version below.

In my experience, C# normally takes around 1/3 the time to execute.  The more PowerShell code you move over to half way decent C# code, the faster your script will be.

This example `MathTime` class has a method that takes a `DateTime`, a `TimeSpan`, and a `long` used to divide the `TimeSpan`.  When called, it returns `[DateTime[]]` containing the initial time, followed by a `[DateTime]` for each dividing point and the final `[DateTime]'.

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
public static class MathTime {
    public static DateTime[] TimeSplitter(DateTime startTime, TimeSpan timeSpan, long divider) {
        long dTicks= timeSpan.Ticks / divider;
        DateTime[] DateTimes = new DateTime[divider + 1];
        DateTimes[0] = startTime;
        for (int I = 1; I <= divider; I++) {
            DateTimes[I] = DateTimes[I-1].AddTicks(dTicks);
        }
        return DateTimes;
    }
}
'@
```

The following PowerShell code gives the above C# a test run:

```
# Example range
$StartDate = (get-date).Addminutes(-10000)
$EndDate = (get-date) 
foreach ($Time in [MathTime]::TimeSplitter([datetime]::Now, ($EndDate - $StartDate), 4)) {
    $Time
}
```

Producing this output:

```
Thursday, March 9, 2023 10:05:29 PM 
Saturday, March 11, 2023 3:45:29 PM 
Monday, March 13, 2023 9:25:29 AM   
Wednesday, March 15, 2023 3:05:29 AM
Thursday, March 16, 2023 8:45:29 PM
```

A some adjustment to the PowerShell will produce similar output to your code:

```
$StartDate = (get-date).Addminutes(-10000)
$EndDate = (get-date)
$LastTime = $null
$FirstTime = $true
foreach ($Time in [MathTime]::TimeSplitter([datetime]::Now, ($EndDate - $StartDate), 4)) {
    if($LastTime) {
        $Start = if($FirstTime) {$LastTime} else {$LastTime.AddSeconds(1)}
        $End = $Time
        $FirstTime = $false
        Write-Host($Start)
        Write-Host($End)
        ' '
    }
    $LastTime = $Time
}
```

Producing this:

```
3/9/2023 10:46:24 PM
3/11/2023 4:26:24 PM 

3/11/2023 4:26:25 PM 
3/13/2023 10:06:24 AM

3/13/2023 10:06:25 AM
3/15/2023 3:46:24 AM 

3/15/2023 3:46:25 AM 
3/16/2023 9:26:24 PM
```

The C# could be written to return an array of arrays of `DateTime`, or an array of elements of a class that has a `start` and `end` members.  The PowerShell code to use this class would probably look something like this:

```
# Example range
$StartDate = (get-date).Addminutes(-10000)
$EndDate = (get-date) 
foreach ($Span in [MathTime]::TimeSplitter([datetime]::Now, ($EndDate - $StartDate), 4)) {
    Write-Host($Span.Start)
    Write-Host($Span.End)
    ' '
}
```

I don't have the time at the moment to write such a class, but this should give you an idea of what could be done.

### UPDATED VERSION:

This C# code provides a class called `DateTimeSpan` that holds 2 `DateTime` members, `start` and `end`, and has a static method `TimeSplitter` that takes a start time, time span, and a number used to divide the time span in to smaller times spans.  It returns an array of `DateTimeSpan` holding the resulting sets of start and end times.

**NOTE:**
This code takes into consideration the fact that there should be a 1 second division between each timespan.

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
public class DateTimeSpan {
    public DateTime Start;
    public DateTime End;
    public DateTimeSpan(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
    public static DateTimeSpan[] TimeSplitter(DateTime startTime, TimeSpan timeSpan, long divider) {
        long TicksUsedByOneSecondDivisions = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * (divider -1);
        long TicksOfEachSpan = (timeSpan.Ticks - TicksUsedByOneSecondDivisions) / divider;
        DateTimeSpan[] DateTimeSpans = new DateTimeSpan[divider];
        DateTime Start = startTime;
        DateTime End = startTime.AddTicks(TicksOfEachSpan);
        for (int I = 0; I < divider; I++) {
            DateTimeSpans[I] = new DateTimeSpan(Start, End);
            Start = Start.AddTicks(TicksOfEachSpan + TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
            End = End.AddTicks(TicksOfEachSpan + TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
        }
        return DateTimeSpans;
    }
}
'@
```

This example use divides the timespan by 4 and produces output similar to the question.

```
$StartDate = (get-date).Addminutes(-10000)
$EndDate = (get-date)
$LastTime = $null
$FirstTime = $true
Write-Host "Start: $StartDate"
Write-Host "End: $EndDate"
Write-Host
foreach ($DTS in [DateTimeSpan]::TimeSplitter($StartDate, ($EndDate - $StartDate), 4)) {
    Write-Host $DTS.Start
    Write-Host $DTS.End
    Write-Host
}
```

This is the output.

```
Start: 03/03/2023 09:03:53
End: 03/10/2023 07:43:53

3/3/2023 9:03:53 AM     
3/5/2023 2:43:53 AM     

3/5/2023 2:43:54 AM     
3/6/2023 8:23:53 PM     

3/6/2023 8:23:54 PM 
3/8/2023 2:03:53 PM 

3/8/2023 2:03:54 PM 
3/10/2023 7:43:53 AM
```

Comment: So I can just call this normally in powershell code?

Comment: @MikeQ, in the updated version section, the first and second blocks are PowerShell code. If you place them in a new ps1 file, in the order presented, and run the ps1 file, the output will be what you see in the third block. At the time I presented the answer I didn't really think about what you are asking, and what is likely causing your performance issues.  Santiago's answer will likely buy more performance.  But, any PS code re-written in C# will almost always be notably faster, so I'm leaving my answer as a example to give you a starting point if you want to convert something in the future.